# tbl_Summary count by distinct ID

Tags: gtsummary

I have a long table for example:

-
| ID| Gene | Result | Category
|:---- |:------:| -----:|:------:|
| 1  | BRCA1    | Pos |Tissue|
| 1  | ATM    | Pos |Tissue|
| 2  | BRCA1    | Neg|Liquid|
| 2 | ATM    | Neg |Tissue|
| 3 | BRCA1    | Pos |Liquid|

Trying to get a summary grouped by Category AND result but have it count per ID not per row.

See photo for example output

I have successfully created a table to stratify by both variables (result and category) using the code below however, the total count at the top for N(liquid) and N(Tissue) is giving me the total count of ID's not stratified by category. Also the total count for Negative N=, Positive N= is counting rows not distinct ID. How can I achieve counting by distinct ID for both overall at the top?

Code used:

```
`Genes%>%
select (Gene, Result,Category)%>%
mutate (Category=paste("Category",Category))%>%
tbl_strata(
strata=testcategory,
.tbl_fun=
~.x%>%
tbl_summary(by=Result,missing="no")%>%
add_n(group_by(Genes$Category)),
.header="**{strata}**, N={n_distinct(Genese$ID)}" )`
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AorPC.png)

Comment: please share data or a snippet of data so we can help further

Comment: Posted a photo in the question for clarification

Comment: share your input data as `dput(df)` and copy that into your question, it is hard to help from pictures.  also please share any code you have tried.

Comment: Done but output table was too hard to form so kept in picture format.